# Can Wix 3.6 be used in a self-contained build?

Tags: .net, msbuild, wix, wix3.6

I was using Wix 3.5 in a self-contained build, meaning other developers (and the build server) don't have to install Wix on their machine for the build to work. I tried upgrading to Wix 3.6 but am unable to get the self-containment part to work. This is what was in the .wixproj in 3.5:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
  <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
  <ProductVersion>3.5</ProductVersion>
  <ProjectGuid>{76b3b6eb-1ea0-4c4c-91aa-da489c0eec25}</ProjectGuid>
  <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  <OutputName>Setup</OutputName>
  <OutputType>Package</OutputType>
  <WixToolPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Lib\WiX\bin\</WixToolPath>
  <WixTasksPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Lib\WiX\WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
  <WixTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Lib\WiX\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here's what I did:

- Replaced all Wix files in ..\Lib\WiX
- Changed `ProductVersion` to 3.6
- Removed the 'bin' in `WixToolPath` since all bin files are now in the WiX root

Other than that, I'm not sure what to do. Visual Studio 2012 complains that 'The application which this project type is based on was not found'. Help?

Comment: VS 2010 obviously complains about the missing project type, which is installed along with the WiX Toolset, if you install it the normal way. I'm not sure whether VS 2010 behaves differently. I think it will still complain about the project type, however you'll be able to build with MSBuild from the command line.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko VS2010 didn't complain about having WiX 3.5 set up this way (not installed on the machine). It would still build the wix project. I'd like the same for WiX 3.6/VS2012

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this Wix documentation page for using Wix in a self-contained build if you are using MSBuild.
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/daily_builds.htm

But, still using Visual Studio build is a far cry. But, probably you will be able to edit your Wix project file in this model to achieve this somehow.